# android - java - pass values through intents, bundles or Parcelables?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, bundle, parcelable

### Context:

Android

I read a lot of examples on the net for passing datas between activities.

What I learned :

- Pass primitive datas through Intents (intent.putExtra(key,value))
- Bundle the primitive datas and put it in an intent.putExtra(key,bundle object)
- Parcelables -> for complex objects and primitives.

Before you say it, yes, I *certainly* missed something.

### Question:

Well, it seems that there are multiple ways to achieve the same goal.

If I want to pass a custom object, a Parcelable is my man. BUT I will still have to "serialize" it, so in the end, I will also have primitives, right ?

To pass primitives, why should I use a bundle when passing directly in an intent will make it too ?

The android documentation / forums / blogs examples did not make it for me. My C background still holds me back a bit.

**Why having 3 different ways to achieve one goal, by the way ?**

Comment: Parcelable is more efficient. Use http://parcelabler.com to make your parcelables. Bundles can contain parcelables.

Comment: So, that is it ? For all my cases, I should forget about the other possibilities and only use Parcelable ? Why are the other still there then ? Backward compat ?

Comment: Or better yet, try not to pass big objects between activities, instead, pass `id's` and retrieve the object from the cache, and such. ;)

Comment: @MartínMarconcini: That is massively interesting => you mean that I should get it back with the R.blah thing ?

Comment: Some interesting article comparing Parcelable and Serializable regarding performance : [http://www.developerphil.com/parcelable-vs-serializable/](http://www.developerphil.com/parcelable-vs-serializable/)

Comment: @D4r7h:  i read that article already thanks :) i think Martin has a very nice solution.

Comment: Well, I don't know what you're trying to pass, but the whole concept of serializing creates a lot of overhead. For a couple of small things, it's maybe ok, but perhaps you should be asking yourself, why do I need to pass this "complex" object between activities? Wouldn't it be better and cleaner if there was a common place (cache?) where these things are stored and I just have an easy way to retrieve them? Then you only pass an integer or a string with a "key". My comment doesn't directly reply to your question, but should give you another point of view

Comment: @MartínMarconcini : this is exactly the kind of answer  I love. And I absolutely like it Martin. Efficient, straight to the goal.

Comment: @Larry glad you find it useful ;) Happy coding!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> BUT I will still have to "serialize" it, so in the end, I will also have primitives, right ?

Pretty much everything in Java eventually boils down to primitives.

> To pass primitives, why should I use a bundle when passing directly in an intent will make it too ?

Either way works. Use whichever makes you feel more comfortable. However, just watch out for collisions on keys (e.g., your activity, and a some base activity of yours that you inherit from, both trying to put the same thing in the same key of the `Intent` or `Bundle`).

> Why having 3 different ways to achieve one goal, by the way ?

I am going to guess that "one goal" is "to pass data from one activity to another". That involves inter-process communication (IPC), even if the two activities are in the same process, as a core OS process is involved in the routing. For pretty much everything outside of streams from a `ContentProvider` in standard Android, IPC means that data has to be put into a `Parcel`, which gets converted into a byte array for passing across the process boundary.

`Parcelable` represents an interface that can be added to custom classes to allow them to be put into a `Parcel`.

`Bundle` is a concrete class that implements `Parcelable` and represents a `HashMap`-like structure, but strongly typed to things that are known to be able to go into a `Parcel`. `Bundle` is more convenient than a `Parcel` for developers, in that it offers random access by key, where `Parcel` does not.

`Intent` extras are merely a `Bundle`, for which `Intent` exposes its own accessor methods.

> For all my cases, I should forget about the other possibilities and only use Parcelable ?

AFAIK, what EpicPandaForce was referring to was the comparison between `Serializable` and `Parcelable`. Either can go into a `Bundle` or a `Parcel`. Of the two, all else being equal, `Serializable` is slower, because it assumes that the serialized form has to be durable, able to be read in again months or years later. `Parcelable` assumes that everyone is working off of the same class definition and can bypass some `Serializable` overhead as a result.

That being said, it's a micro-optimization.

> Why are the other still there then ?

Not everything can be made to extend `Parcelable`, notably `java.*` classes. `Integer`, for example, is not `Parcelable`. Yet, we would like to be able to pass `int` and `Integer` values around. Hence, `Parcel` supports `int`, as does `Bundle`.

> you mean that I should get it back with the R.blah thing

AFAIK, in that comment, Mr. Marconcini was referring to "id" as a general concept, not referring to `R.id` values specifically. For example, if you are maintaining an image cache, rather than passing around actual `Bitmap` objects, pass around some identifier that points back to the cache.

Comment: Yes, Thanks Commons, I was referring to exactly that. Pass the `key` and retrieve again. In my opinion, for a small thing, passing a Serializable/Parceable object is "fine" but for the most part, it's better to keep everything clean and just have a solid cache/retrieve mechanism.

Comment: Isn't there is a way to only send an int, which would be the unique id of an object ?

Comment: @Larry: If you have such an `int`, and that `int` is the key to whatever sort of data structure that you are using to hold objects, sure. For example, data in SQLite automatically has a `ROWID` value in each row, which is a unique `long` for that row in that table, that you might leverage.

Comment: yes , but a random object doesn't seems to have that when i create it with new. :( -> wait getting the hash may help here

Comment: @Larry your object will not exist anymore while trying to get the hash in your other activity. The only purpose of passing an id for your object is to retrieve it with or recreate it from this id, for example if you call a webservice with this id, or if you make a select statement from a database.

Comment: @D4r7h: Exact, but I don't see how I could do that. Says for example I create an object, how could I pass it to another activity by an id that both activities can understand and find/reconstruct back ? That would avoid serialization completely :), like mmap.

Comment: @Larry: I don't think there is :/... And by that I mean without any sort of storage.

Comment: @Larry: "how could I pass it to another activity by an id that both activities can understand and find/reconstruct back ?" -- there are plenty of cases where this works out fine, usually because you already have some centralized data store (e.g., singleton cache manager).

Comment: @CommonsWare: so every items i plan to pass should be created and reside in a singleton. That is the solution i guess..

Comment: @Larry: "so every items i plan to pass should be created and reside in a singleton" -- probably not. "Every" is a very strong term. Different situations call for different approaches.

Comment: @Larry take a look at Realm DB (realm.io is the URL). It's a very simple way to persist information without having to deal with SQLite.

Comment: @MartínMarconcini: thanks a lot for the pointer Martin. Will have a look at it :)

Answer (score 1):

Using Parcelable is recommended if you're passing objects with non serializables. It means you can implement a serializable representation of your objects yourself to ensure the data is what you expect to be passed back and forward between activities.

If you're passing a simple id or a string back and forward by all means use intent.putExtra()

I found this article on the topic very useful to help understand the differences and benefits between the options:
http://www.developerphil.com/parcelable-vs-serializable/